# How to select last observation of every year in xts object

Tags: r

I have a xts file that consists of monthly closing prices of 2000 stocks from year 2000-2019. Now I want to select last observation of every year.

```
library(Quantmod)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
to.yearly(myxtsfile)
```

to.yearly code it do not work. I think it works only on OHLC. Please suggest some better way so that i can have last observation of every year for every stock.

Comment: Welcome to SO (your're not a "new contributor", but you seems quite new). Could you add some data?

Comment: `to.yearly` transforms the data from daily (monthly) to yearly data. It does not select the last record of the year. the to.xxx functions return the open / close over the period plus the highest high and lowest low during the period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using xts and zoo package. No need to use Quantmod.

```
library(xts)
library(zoo)
last_observation<-do.call(rbind, lapply(split(myxtsfile, "years"), last, "1 month"))
```

Comment: Tnx @simar it works

Comment: @jeetkamal, Be aware that this only works if the data is monthly data. If the data would be daily, this will return the last month of each year. Not the last record of the year.

Comment: @jeetkamal, phiver is absolutely right. If there is daily data just include only last in the above command.